# google play services resources not found error

Tags: unity, android, google-play-services

Everything used to work till yesterday but suddenly today I am getting this error as "Google play services resources not found".What may be the reason for it?

Comment: When do you get those messages?

Comment: When at astart I try "Social.locaclUser" also when click Login button....Previously it used to work properly

Comment: Unity does NOT have an implementation for Google play. Only for GameCenter (iOS).

You need this instead : https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

This has an implementation for Social. You enable it and then you can access Social.localUser.

Just make sure you also have included all jar files. https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver

Comment: Yes that was I doing, turns out it was some weired bug not related to Play services, I was deleting Gameobject itself so it was not getting initilaise